# Automate multiple registrations of 'sender' accounts for Android C2DM?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I'm wondering if it is possible to develop a script to submit multiple apps - ALL AT ONE GO OR ONE BYE ONE - to Android Cloud to Device Messaging  (https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup).

We have multiple apps to register on a regular basis and it is too time-consuming to do this manually everytime.

We *understand* that it is technically possible, but does Google policy allow this?

**Note:**
I am aware that there is no API.
I have tested with script to post to that form and it worked.
I don't mind comments coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to use GSM and there is no way to do via script now!

We have to register manually!